# Why no JTAG connection?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, jtag, hardware, quartus-ii

This used to work before I installed Quartus v10 to ensure backward-compatibility. Now I get no hardware found in Quartus both v13 and v10. The USB-Blaster used to show up, then I installed Quartus v10 to support old .ptr files and now the JTAG connection with the DE2 board is broken. Why? Is it because I installed Quartus v10? Then that is not logical. What is the explanation and what should be done?

Comment: Maybe you broke the blaster's driver when you installed V10 try finding the latest blaster driver installer on Altera's website and installing it manually.

Comment: Yes, when I uninstalled v13, then v10 started working and got a JTAG connection.

Comment: If you have to run multiple versions of Quartus on a machine; you may have to change environment variables in your OS to switch between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altera tools are finicky sometimes. I've had issues with them similar to what you describe.
What I do when it gets to this point is do to device driver and uninstall whatever driver is there. If needed, display hidden devices. Then reattach the device and reinstall the drivers that come in the Quartus II 13 directory.

By the way, its best for you to stop using Quartus II 10 if possible. I say that because Altera only supports up to 3 versions back. Version 10 is already outdated and won't be supported by them. There are plenty of fixes in the new versions (and sometimes some new issues) and some versions are really bad about device support.

Comment: Guess what, I uninstalled v13 and then v10 got a connection. I have to use v10 to keep compatibility with ptr files.

Comment: FPGAs can however be an extreme case of wanting to do project updates with the same toolchain as created the original.  In an ideal world designs should not push limits and tools should be bug/quirk free, but in practice, something that worked and made timing (or fit!) with one version of the tools can fail with another.  So unless a project is under active development it may make sense to keep building tiny fixes using the original tools.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `jtagd`, a deamon between the Altera tools and the driver, is running.

If you're running Linux, the QuartusII software changed the way it communicates with the driver around the version change when your problem started. Before they used `usbfs`, which is no longer the case.

You don't state what operating system you are using, but here are a few things to check if you're running Linux (from http://www.fpga-dev.com/altera-usb-blaster-with-ubuntu/ which gives more details, especially see the section on trouble shooting):

- Disconnect and connect the cable, check output of `dmesg|tail` for anything about an Altera device. Also see if `lsusb|grep Altera` finds anything. If not, this is not a device driver problem, but rather a problem with the cable/board.
- Run `jtagconfig`, see if it finds the JTAG device(s). It probably won't, if the devices is not recognized byt the Altera graphical tools. If `jtagconfig` is failing, you will see

  ```
  $ jtagconfig
  No JTAG hardware available
  ```
- If the result from the previous point is negative, try the below sequence of commands. If devices are found now, this indicates a permission problem since we have now been running everything as root:

  ```
  $ sudo killall -9 jtagd   # Kill jtagd, ...
  $ sudo killall -9 jtagd   # ...and verify jtagd is indeed not running.
  jtagd: no process found   # Good, verified.
  $ jtagconfig
  1) CV SoCKit [2-1]
    02D020DD   5CSEBA6(.|ES)/5CSEMA6/..
    4BA00477   SOCVHPS
  ```